# UITextField inside a custom UIView (InfoWindow) - The keyboard doesn't show up when I select the input

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitextfield, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm making a custom InfoWindow for my markers. I followed the official Google Tutorial : [Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILiBXYscsyY)

Here is my `.xib`

[image]

User interaction is enabled...

My infoWindow show up above the marker as you can see on the screenshot :
[image]

But when I click on the pseudo input, the keyboard doesn't show up. Nothing happens!

I don't understand why it does that, because the `user interaction` is enabled...

The full View Tree :
[image]

Comment: Could you provide an image of the full "View Controller Scene" tree?

Comment: I've just Edit my Question, I did put a screenshot of the full view tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/ios/marker?hl=ar-SA#info_windows

Note: The info window is **rendered as an image** each time it is displayed on the map. This means that any changes to its properties while it is active will not be immediately visible. The contents of the info window will be refreshed the next time that it is displayed.

Kind of lame, imho, especially if you have implemented the google maps js API, which provides complete control within any custom infoWindow.

I believe you will need to wire up an entirely separate overlay to make it interactive.

Comment: Yeah... I guess it's just not possible...
I don't understand why they render it as an image...
For me, it doesn't make sense to that. 
Thanks for your explanations.